# how to initialize ArrayObject value to ZERO in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have

```
Cell[,] cells = new Cells[6,6];
I want to initialize it all values to zero
I did something like this
for(int i=1; i<=6;i++) {
  for(int j=1; j<=6; j++) {
    cells[i,j] = 0;
  }
}
```

The problem is it cant convert int 0 to Cell type. How do I initializze them to *zero* for first time?? For eg: I have [6,6] array and I want to assign every Cell[2,3].Value = 0

Thanks

Comment: What is `Cell` ? It is struct or class ? and also `Cell[,] cells = new Cells[6,6];` won't compile

Comment: What is Cell? Have you created a class?

Comment: What in the world is `Cell`? Can it hold `int` values or `string`?

Comment: It is Class Cell{int x, int y, Warrior warrior};

Comment: Class Warrior{int htPoints, int power}

Comment: Please put some more code @Pushpita Shrestha.. So that it will be clear

Comment: You want to initialise the `x` and `y` properties of `Cell` to zero is it?

Comment: I will get the [6,6] array at the beginning, so I want to assign all the cell value to 0 at first

Comment: @PushpitaShrestha - did you try `cells[i,j].x = 0;` and `cells[i,j].y = 0;`?

Comment: or you can user contructor public Cell(){ x = 0; y = 0; warrier =new Warrier } ? any object created by default will be initialized with default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is it cant convert int 0 to Cell type. How do I initializze them to zero for first time??

Going by your Class make `x` and `y` public first (assuming you are accessing them in methods not in your `Cell` class:

```
class Cell
{
    public int x;
    public int y; 
    Warrior warrior;
};
```

Then you should get access to your class members:

```
Cell[,] cells = new Cells[6,6];

for(int i=0; i<6;i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++) 
    {
        cells[i,j].x = cells[i,j].y = 0;
    }
}
```

The above is for resetting the values to `0`. If you want this on initialization then create a constructor:

```
Cell(Warrior getWarrior)
{ 
    x = 0; 
    y = 0; 
    warrior = getWarrior;
}
```

Cells[,] cells = new Cells[6, 6];

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        cells[i, j]= new Cells(sendWarrior);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} {1}", cells[i, j].x, cells[i, j].y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to print Console.Write("\t{0}", cells[i,j]) but it throws unhandled exception. Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.

Comment: @PushpitaShrestha - it will throw that exception - print this way - `Console.Write("\t{0}", cells[i,j].x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like that:

```
class Cell {
  public int x {get; set;}
  public int y {get; set;} 
  Warrior warrior {get; set;} 
};

Cell[,] cells = new Cells[6, 6];

// Arrays are zero-based in C#, so they start with 0
for(int i = 0; i < Cells.GetLength(0); i++) // <- Better get length than put "6"
  for(int j = 0; j < Cells.GetLength(1); j++) 
    cells[i, j] = new Cell() { // <- Do not forget to create Cell
      x = 0, // <- Overshoot, x will be 0 by default, to show the trick only
      y = 0  // <- Overshoot, y will be 0 by default, to show the trick only
    };
```

Comment: I am not sure how this code is any better than what OP has already posted.